# Is a creature considered to have died if it has negative toughness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Ok so let's say my opponent has a [Festering Mummy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFestering%20Mummy%5d) (It's a 1/1 and when it dies put a -1/-1/ counter on target creature) and I cast [Splendid Agony](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426811) (Distribute two -1/-1 counters among one or two target creatures) and I put a -1/-1 on the Festering Mummy, is it considered to have died and does its death effect still occur?

Answer (score 11):

Festering Mummy's triggered ability will trigger.

"To die" is synonymous with "to move from the battlefield to the graveyard" (for any reason). This includes when State-Based Actions move a creature to the graveyard for having negative toughness.

Answer (score 5):

**Creatures that have 0 or less toughness will "*Die*" according to state-based actions.**

This is covered by the following two rules:

> **704.5f**: If a creature has toughness 0 or less, it’s put into its owner’s graveyard. Regeneration can’t replace this event.

and

> **700.4:** The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”

---

So for your specific example what will happen is:

1. You cast [Splendid Agony](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426811) targeting your opponent's [Festering Mummy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426793).
2. It resolves placing one -1/-1 counter on Festering Mummy.
3. State-based actions see that Festering Mummy has 0 toughness, and moves it to the graveyard (i.e. Festering Mummy *dies*).
4. Festering Mummy's death ability triggers and goes on the stack.